# Write AWS Elasticache (Redis) Query Output To S3 Path

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I want to get all the keys from AWS Redis DB exported to an S3 path as text file so that I can analyze the keys that are getting created in the db.

How can I export all the keys from redis-cli to a S3 path?

Can this command be used to write to a S3 path?

`redis-cli -h 10.1.xx.xx -n 1 keys * >s3://bucket/path/filename.txt`

Comment: No, the shell doesn't understand s3:// paths, that's only for aws specific tools. You can write to a file locally and then upload it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html), you can copy your local file to your s3 in the command line.

```
# copy a single file to a specified bucket and key
aws s3 cp test.txt s3://mybucket/test2.txt

# upload a local file stream from standard input to a specified bucket and key
aws s3 cp - s3://mybucket/stream.txt
```

So, you can upload your stdout to your s3 like this

```
redis-cli -h 10.1.xx.xx -n 1 keys * | aws s3 cp - s3://bucket/path/filename.txt
```